# Mahout: "Error creating assembly archive job"

Tags: java, maven, mahout

I'm trying to install [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) on a Ubuntu 12.10 server but I'm running into a build error and i can't figure out where it's failing.

The error message if i'm running it without the -e flag is:

```
Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
```

The steps to reproduce this error are:

1. Checkout the repo with: `svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk`
2. cd trunk/
3. `mvn install -e`

**mvn -version output:**

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.7.0_17
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
```

**mvn install -e output:**

```
Tests run: 689, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] Building jar: /root/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [jar:test-jar {execution: default}]
[INFO] Building jar: /root/trunk/core/target/mahout-core-0.8-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: job}]
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/job.xml
[WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm:pom:3.1:compile' is invalid.

Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:495)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.ArchiveCreationException: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:436)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: error in opening zip file
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:472)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter.ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.finalizeArchiveCreation(ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.runArchiveFinalizers(AbstractArchiver.java:884)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:908)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:512)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:186)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:158)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.getEntries(PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.getResources(AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.proxy.PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.getResources(PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:468)
        ... 25 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the problem by installing `maven` (Apache Maven 3.0.4) instead of the `maven2` package and removing the `~/.m2/` directory.